# Why does my object not need to call the .toString method?

Tags: java, object, polymorphism

In my test class at the bottom of my code you can see a bunch of system.out.print's. My question is: why doesn't the stack object need to be written as stack.toString() (It's written system.out.print(stack) instead). Does the print statement dynamically call the toString() method because it is the only string method available in the class....or is it something else gong on?

```
public class Char_Stack {
private char [] array = new char[10];
private int top = 0;

public int size() {
    return top;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return top == 0;
}

public void push(char value) throws StackFullException {
    if (top == array.length)    
    throw new StackFullException("StackFullException");
    array[top++] = value;   
}

public double top() throws StackEmptyException {
    if (top == 0)
    throw new StackEmptyException("StackEmptyException");   
    return array[top-1];        
}

public double pop() throws StackEmptyException {
    if (top == 0)
    throw new StackEmptyException("StackEmptyException");
    return array[--top];

}

public String toString() {
    String out = "[" + top + " / " + array.length + "]";
    for (int i=0;i<array.length; i++) {
        out += " " + array[i];
    }
    return out;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws StackFullException,StackEmptyException {
    Char_Stack stack = new Char_Stack();

    stack.push('Y');
    System.out.println(stack);

    stack.push('P');
    System.out.println(stack);

    stack.push('P');
    System.out.println(stack);

    stack.push('A');
    System.out.println(stack);

    stack.push('H');
    System.out.println(stack);

    stack.pop();
    System.out.println(stack);

    stack.pop();
    System.out.println(stack);

    stack.pop();
    System.out.println(stack);

    stack.pop();
    System.out.println(stack);

    stack.pop();
    System.out.println(stack);
}
```

}

Comment: How much would it hurt to [read the Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(java.lang.Object))?

Comment: because Java is smart :)

Comment: Feel free to see how [`println(Object)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/io/PrintStream.java#PrintStream.println%28java.lang.Object%29) works internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roughly speaking, yes, it does. It will "try its best" to print it. What happens is that  `System.out.println(object)` calls `String.valueOf(object)` which in turns  calls `object.toString()`.

Answer (score 1):

[`System.out.println()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.Object%29) does that for you.

> Prints an Object and then terminate the line. **This method calls at first String.valueOf(x) to get the printed object's string value**, then behaves as though it invokes print(String) and then println().

[`String.valueOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Object%29)

> if the argument is null, then a string equal to "null"; otherwise, **the value of obj.toString() is returned**.

Answer (score 0):

Found this too: It helped me understand a bit better https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString